# Error while creating Hive/Hbase Table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

Failed to create Hive Table.

Here is the log

```
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000> CREATE TABLE hbase_table_1(key int, value string) 
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000> STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000> WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,cf1:val")
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000> TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "xyz");
```

...

```
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return   code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:java.io.IOException: Attempt to start meta tracker failed.
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.catalog.CatalogTracker.start(CatalogTracker.java:204)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.startCatalogTracker(HBaseAdmin.java:262)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.getCatalogTracker(HBaseAdmin.java:235)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.tableExists(HBaseAdmin.java:306)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.tableExists(HBaseAdmin.java:322)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler.preCreateTable(HBaseStorageHandler.java:200)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:664)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:657)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:156)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.createTable(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:714)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.createTable(DDLTask.java:4135)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:306)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:160)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:88)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1650)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1409)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1192)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1059)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1054)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runQuery(SQLOperation.java:154)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.access$100(SQLOperation.java:71)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$1$1.run(SQLOperation.java:206)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1556)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$1.run(SQLOperation.java:218)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Caused by: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/meta-region-server
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1041)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.watchAndCheckExists(ZKUtil.java:427)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperNodeTracker.start(ZooKeeperNodeTracker.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.catalog.CatalogTracker.start(CatalogTracker.java:200)
    ... 35 more
) (state=08S01,code=1)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is looking for /hbase location in zookeeper but it is not present. Can you verify in your zookeeper ,if above /hbase location is present?